# Cannot zip files with the same name?

Tags: zip

I could not believe this: it seems that the zip specification does not allow two different files with the same file name going into one zip file.

In my case I use an external file to specify all the files I wanna zip.
This could look like this:

../Website1/favicon.ico
../Website2/favicon.ico

and there we are, that's not possible, despite keeping the directory structure. You would expect the name to be <../Website1/favicon.ico> rather than  but that does not seem to be the case, I get:

"Invalid ZIP request (cannot repeat names in Zip file)"

with WinZip. I tried the same with 7Zip - same result.

Strangely googling did not show many hits that really fit but those I found seem to confirm my findings. That's hard to believe since this limitation is very severe. I actually struggle to understand why this did not hit me a couple of decades earlier.

Am I overlooking something very basic here?

Comment: What command line are you using to create this? or is it via the GUI? if you didn't tell WinZip/7Zip to retain the directory structure, the error you are seeing will show up

Comment: I tried the same in 7-Zip on Windows 7 and it works. Maybe you have some strange configuration issues?

Answer (score 1):

To be precise:

Adding these two files:

```
C:\Temp\Website1\FavIcon
C:\Temp\Website2\FavIcon
```

results in a single file; the last `Add` wins...

This however:

```
Website1\FavIcon
Website2\FavIcon
```

results in a zip file that contains both files.